# Comparing floating point preprocessor definitions safely

Tags: c, floating-point, c-preprocessor

In order to detect if the C implementation treats `long double` as `double` or as another type, I'm checking the preprocessor definitions from `<float.h>`, (ie: `LDBL_*` and `DBL_*`). Some of them are integer literals, others are floating point literals. When comparing the float ones, I get the typical *"comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe"* (a warning I always enable because it's useful).

Then I thought to perform the comparison on the preprocessor instead, but it cannot handle floating point literals comparisons, so it doesn't seem to be an option.

Can I compare floating point literals without getting any warning even if the `-Wfloat-equal` warning is enabled? How? (it doesn't matter if the test is performed at runtime or by the preprocessor).

I would prefer a C90 or C99 solution but, if that's not possible, post-C99 solutions would be welcome as well.

Comment: Is the question about comparing floating point literals or determining if `long double` and `double` are the same underlying type? For the latter, comparing the `sizeof` may be sufficient (what would be the point in having different types of the same size?).

Comment: You could use the `<` and `>` operators: `if (LDBL_MAX < DBL_MAX || LDBL_MAX > DBL_MAX) printf("LDBL_MAX != DBL_MAX\n");`.

Comment: Of course, C treats `double` and `long double` as different types even if they have the same representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to compare the floating-point constants because they are fully determined by the integer parameters of the floating-point types, other than the unreliable case where `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM` or `LDBL_HAS_SUBNORM` is −1. (In that case, `DBL_TRUE_MIN` and `LDBL_TRUE_MIN` would be unreliable, so comparing them would be an unreliable indication of whether the types would behave the same.)

In the following, *b* is `FLT_RADIX` (the same radix for `float`, `double`, and `long double`), *d* is the base-*b* digit *b*−1, and there are `DBL_MANT_DIG` digits after the radix point. The `DBL` constants are described, and the `LDBL` constants are analogous.

`DBL_MAX` equals 0.*ddd*…*ddd*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *e* is `DBL_MAX_EXP`.

`DBL_MIN` equals 0.100…000•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *e* is `DBL_MIN_EXP`.

`DBL_TRUE_MIN` equals `DBL_MIN` or 0.000…001•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *e* is `DBL_MIN_EXP`, according to whether `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM` is 0 or 1, respectively.

`DBL_EPSILON` equals 0.000…001•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> where *e* is 1.

Therefore, comparing the integer parameters provides all the information that comparing the floating-point constants does.

If it were necessary to compare floating-point constants, options include:

- Replace `a == b` with `! (a < b || a > b)`.
- Put the comparisons in a separate translation unit and compile it without `-Wfloat-equal`.
- Use Clang instead of GCC, as Clang appears not to warn when comparing floating-point constant expressions, even with `-Wfloat-equal` enabled.

Comment: Perhaps a sample code where "comparing the integer parameters provides all the information that comparing the floating-point constants does." to fulfill "detect if the C implementation treats long double as double or as another type"?

Comment: Well, actually what I'm doing is just `(sizeof(long double)==sizeof(double)) && (LDBL_MANT_DIG == DBL_MANT_DIG)`, which is just integers. But later, for catching weird cases, I also verify if floating point literals also match, and throw a warning otherwise (in the lines of "long double looks like double but unexpected values mismatches found"). And this later test was the one rising the `-Wfloat-equal` warnings. Very complete answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: @cesss "verify if floating point literals also match," --> Use `static_assert()`.